# VBA - Clear Cells of Found (Dynamic) Range Up to Last Row

Tags: excel, vba

This is pretty much the same question posted here:

[Excel VBA - How to clear a dynamic range (from below header, to last row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163314/excel-vba-how-to-clear-a-dynamic-range-from-below-header-to-last-row)

However, given that this is an old thread AND the solutions provided are not working, I am posting the question in the way I am trying to solve my problem.

Two solutions found here for finding correct column:

[VBA - Find a column with a specific header and find sum of all the rows in that column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122393/vba-find-a-column-with-a-specific-header-and-find-sum-of-all-the-rows-in-that)

https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4879-excel-select-column-by-header-name.html

Solution for Clearing Contents found here:

[Excel VBA - How to clear a dynamic range (from below header, to last row)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163314/excel-vba-how-to-clear-a-dynamic-range-from-below-header-to-last-row)

Here is what I have tried to make work:

```
With ActiveSheet

    xStr = "Product Folder"

    Set aCell = .Range("B2:J2").Find(What:=xStr, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

    'If Found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

        col = aCell.Column
        colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)

        lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

        'This is your range
        Set Rng = .Range(colName & "2" & lRow)

    'If not found
    Else

        MsgBox "Column Not Found"

    End If

    Range(Rng).Resize(Rows.count - 1, Columns.count).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents

End With
```

I can get ALL the information required (Column, Header, Range ect) but I cannot seem to find a way of clearing the contents.

With the code as is above, I get the error:

> Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

I have tried changing

```
    lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    'This is your range
    Set Rng = .Range(colName & "2" & lRow)
```

To this:

```
    lRow = Range(colName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    'This is your range
    Set Rng = Range(colName & "2" & lRow)
```

And this line:

```
Range(Rng).Resize(Rows.count - 1, Columns.count).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
```

To this:

```
Rng.Resize(Rows.count - 1, Columns.count).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
```

But then I get this error:

> Application-defined or object-defined error

Tried changing this:

```
    'If Found
If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

    col = aCell.Column
    colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)

    lRow = .Range(colName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row

    'This is your range
    Set Rng = .Range(colName & "2" & lRow)

'If not found
Else

    MsgBox "Column Not Found"

End If

Range(Rng).Resize(Rows.count - 1, Columns.count).Offset(1, 0).ClearContents
```

To this:

```
'If Found
    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then

        col = aCell.Column
        colName = Split(.Cells(, col).Address, "$")(1)

        lRow = Range(colName & .Rows.count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

        Set myCol = Range(colName & "2")

        'This is your range
        Set Rng = Range(myCol & ":" & colName & lRow)

    'If not found
    Else

        MsgBox "Column Not Found"

    End If

    Rng.Clear
```

Then I get an error at the `Set Rng` line:

> Method 'Range' of object '_Global' failed

I know the line itself isn't really correct (obviously) but I just don't know how else to get the code to read it as `Range("A2:A" & Lastrow).Clear`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed what causes the error:

`Set Rng = Range(myCol & ":" & colName & lRow)`

The `Range()` requires parameters that are either Ranges or Strings.

Not both. Try this:
`Set Rng = Range(myCol.Address & ":" & colName & lRow)`

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim myCol As Range
    Dim colName As String
    Dim lRow As Long

    Set myCol = Range("A5")
    colName = "A"
    lRow = 15
    Set rng = Range(myCol.Address & ":" & colName & lRow)    
End Sub
```

Or try this, with passing 2 range objects:

```
With Worksheets(1)
    Set rng = .Range(myCol, .Cells(lRow, colName))
End With
```

Comment: Please review 4th line of your answer , perhaps it should be `myCol.Address` instead of `myCol`

Comment: @skkakkar - yup

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) Both work, however, they both clear the contents of the entire column - but I need the header to stay.

Comment: I got it working by adding Offset. Perhaps you would like to add it to your answer and I will mark it as correct :) Set Rng = Range(myCol.Address & ":" & colName & lRow).Offset(1, 0)

Comment: @EitelDagnin - cool that you have figured it out. Do not add the `.Offset()`, it can mistake someone in the future. Furthermore, the answer avoids the error, thus it is ok. :)

Comment: No problem. Thank you for your help :)